# Tacacs Password not visible

Tags: cisco

When logging into the Cisco Device, it will promt for username and password. 
While entering username its visible, Password is not at all seen (even encrypted) what is the reason

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco does this is for security-reasons.

Imagine you're working in an office with your colleagues. It would be horrible if any of your colleagues standing next to you could see your password.

This also is a common practice among other systems like Linux...

If you want to see the password you're typing you could use a SSH to log in and a SSH Client which allows for showing the password you're typing, which i wouldn't recommend.